# my contact name attached to an text message not sent from my phone

Tags: iphone

My wife received a text message on her iPhone with my name in the contact information that was not sent by me. The text was not directed to her and was not sent by me. I contacted our provider and they have no explanation.

Comment: AFAIK she has to have a contact in her phone that has your name associated with the phone number the text came from.  "Name" is not part of what is transported, only the number (or email address) that sent the message, the phone then matches that up to what is in contacts.

Comment: Was it an iMessage (blue) or a standard SMS message (Green)?